# Pandas SettingWithCopy Warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Bear with me, yesterday was my first day using Pandas.

I'm trying to make a backtesting framework for an algorithmic investor, and I'm running into a 'SettingWithCopy' warning. The dataframe I'm working with isn't being edited either, so I think somewhere I'm editing a copy of the dataframe and it's getting thrown out. It gives me a warning at all of the 'df.at' commands.

Additionally to (and I expect related to) the SettingWithCopy warning, the changes I make to the dataframe within the method do not end up appearing in the dataframe that eventually gets returned. As far as I understand the 'df.at' commands I have should be changing the 'transactions' column, but in the output frame that column is just full of NaNs.

How do I fix these issues, and what is the cause so I can avoid this next time? I read the documentation on the warning and I didn't wholly understand it.

Here is the code:

```py
#%%
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import random

def backtest(df):
    # Set wallet properties
    wallet = 1000 # dollas

    #iterate through day by day
    for i in range(len(df)):
        today = df.iloc[i,:]
        print(f"i = {str(i)}")

        signal = random.randint(-1,1)
        print('Signal: ' + str(signal))

        # hold signal
        if signal == 0:
            pass
        # buy signal
        elif signal == 1:
            print('Buying on: ' + str(today['timestamp']) + ' for ' + str(today['close']))
            df.at[i,'transactions'] = 1
            wallet -= today['close']
        # sell signal
        elif signal == -1:
            print('Selling on: ' + str(today['timestamp']) + ' for ' + str(today['close']))
            wallet += today['close']
            df.at[i,'transactions'] = -1
            print(df.at[i,'transactions'])
            print(f"Wallet at ${str(wallet)}")
        df.at[i,'wallet'] = wallet
        print()
    
    return df


# Import the dataset and get it ready to work with
df = pd.read_csv('Data/S&P500_2015-2018.csv')
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# Choose which stock(s) you're using
stock = df[df['symbol'] == 'AMD']

out = backtest(stock)
print('All done backtesting')
out.plot(x = 'timestamp', y = 'transactions')
#%%
```

And here is the output:

```
i = 0
Signal: 1
Buying on: 2015-12-01 05:00:00+00:00 for 2.34

i = 1
Signal: -1
Selling on: 2015-12-02 05:00:00+00:00 for 2.27
-1.0
Wallet at $999.93

i = 2
Signal: 0

i = 3
Signal: 1
Buying on: 2015-12-04 05:00:00+00:00 for 2.28

i = 4
Signal: -1
Selling on: 2015-12-07 05:00:00+00:00 for 2.355
-1.0
Wallet at $1000.005

i = 5
Signal: 1
...

i = 398
Signal: -1
Selling on: 2017-06-30 04:00:00+00:00 for 12.48
<ipython-input-10-c0810f02fee9>:25: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.loc[i,'transactions'] = 1
```

Edit: clarified my question

Comment: when you edit a susbet of the frame, that happens, so each time you slice the frame use the `.copy()` suffix which basically ensures that the user is aware that they are processing the slice of a bigger frame.

Comment: Where am I slicing the frame? Just at the 'stock = ~~~' line, right?